# PySpark XML processing - Ignoring bad records

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I am processing a large XML file using the Spark XML Library (HyukjinKwon:spark-xml:0.1.1-s_2.11). The XML processing fails with an analysis exception for a couple of records. I would like to keep processing the file ignoring these records.

I have the below code for processing the xml and I tried the option of 'DROPMALFORMED' but didn't help.

```
df = (spark.read.format("xml")
      .option("rootTag","Articles")
      .option("rowTag", "Article")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
      .load("/mnt/RawAdl2/problemfile.xml"))

AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '['Affiliation']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''Affiliation'' is of string type.;
```

I would like to drop the malformed records and continue with the processing of the file. Is there any other option I could try? Appreciate the inputs!

EDIT: Looking at the source code [link](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/pull/22/files/3cab3933319bdbee9bd9c314d7a2c70071ffc439#diff-d85018a30b75475a6008ee92c967036b) the Malformed option is supported by the library. As I am not well versed with Scala, I am not really sure whether I am using the correct syntax for this option. Please advise.

After going through the source code, I tried this below code but no luck

```
.option("mode", "DROP_MALFORMED_MODE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the badRecords path:

```
.option("badRecordsPath", "/tmp/badRecordsPath")
```

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/handling-bad-records.html

Comment: I figured out the issue is not with the read and the exception is generated from a select in the same cell. Thanks for your response which pointed out how to handle bad records.